# No sound  on new gaming PC

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Well, as you can probably tell by the title, I have no sound.

I recently built a new gaming PC, and installed 12.04 onto it. Obviously, I have ALSA and PulseAudio installed, but I don't have `/etc/asound.conf`, if that matters.

I also can't tell what my sound driver is, mainly because I don't know how to find it. I did a Google search about it, but to no avail.

There is only one sound I seem to be getting: a white noise-ish, high-frequency sound coming from the headphones.

Note: I have connected the case audio to the HD audio header, not the AC'97, if that matters (though I still get no sound through the speakers, which are connected to the motherboard directly).

Also, my sound card is: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller.

Comment: Sorry I can't help directly with an answer. Though, take a look at the [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) on Ubuntu help pages. HTH.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have followed all of the steps on there, and everything seems to be alright.

Comment: I wrote a sound troubleshooting guide a few months ago, see if it can help: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iTlJ8BfqXUjaHO__TEdlkvuqB1WLOkGaudngc5SFLMI/edit

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04. OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and abandoned the question. VTC as `not reproducible`.